# Why is my cron job not running?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, cron

I am trying to run a cron job at 5:20pm as below but it's not working.

```
20 17 * * 1 /usr/bin/php /home/myacc/public_html/job/generate.php
```

I basically did `crontab -e` and entered the above line there and saved the file.

If I try running the command directly from the command line as below, it works fine:

```
php /home/myacc/public_html/job/generate.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how do I send a message from the cron to either a log file or email so that I know what's going on?

Comment: This should help you out: http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: What does generate.php do? How do you you know that it is not running?

Comment: generate.php has commands to generate a website's sitemap. When it's run, the website's admin section shows the job has been run. When I run it manually, the website's admin tracks that it has run.

Comment: @user1448031: This script runs only on monday 5.20PM. are you checking   admin website only after monday 5.20 PM?

Answer (score 0):

You can record all the logs of your cronjobs by installing postfix and configuring it as local domain during installation. Such that you can see the logs of your cron jobs by `vi /var/mail/<user-name>`. Try looking the logs and figure out the problem. If you don't find any solution post the log so that it will help others to diagnose the problem. I'm adding this as an answer instead of comment because i think I'm answering your second query.